# pyside6 не выравниваются компоненты в layout

Tags: python-3.x, qt, qt-designer, qlayout, pyside6

Что я делаю:

1. Создаю макет формы в QT Designer.
2. Преобразую его в код python с помощью pyuic6
3. Подключаю модуль со своей формой.

Что я получаю: вроде рабочее приложение, но размеры и позиции компонентов в layout-ах не меняются при изменении формы.

Что должно быть: при изменении размеров окна должны менятся размеры и позиции компонентов.

Приношу извинения, но не могу правильно вставить код - может плохо старался, но его часть все равно съезжает.

Исходный код:

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from main_window_form import Ui_main_window_class


class main_form_class(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(main_form_class, self).__init__()
        self.main_window_form = Ui_main_window_class()
        self.main_window_form.setupUi(self)
        self.main_window_form.pushButton_1.clicked.connect(self.push_button_1_clicked)
        self.main_window_form.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.push_button_2_clicked)
        self.main_window_form.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.push_button_3_clicked)
        self.main_window_form.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.push_button_4_clicked)


    def push_button_1_clicked(self):
        self.main_window_form.label.setText(self.main_window_form.lineEdit.text())

    def push_button_2_clicked(self):
        self.main_window_form.label_2.setText(self.main_window_form.lineEdit.text())

    def push_button_3_clicked(self):
        self.main_window_form.label_3.setText(self.main_window_form.lineEdit.text())

    def push_button_4_clicked(self):
        self.main_window_form.label_4.setText(self.main_window_form.lineEdit.text())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication()
    Main_Window = main_form_class()
    Main_Window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**main_window_form.py**:

```
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit,
    QMainWindow, QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget)

class Ui_main_window_class(object):
    def setupUi(self, main_window_class):
        if not main_window_class.objectName():
            main_window_class.setObjectName(u"main_window_class")
        main_window_class.setEnabled(True)
        main_window_class.resize(630, 743)
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(main_window_class.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        main_window_class.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(main_window_class)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.widget = QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setObjectName(u"widget")
        self.widget.setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 611, 401))
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setSpacing(10)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_5")
        self.verticalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(u"lineEdit")

        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit)

        self.label_5 = QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_5.setObjectName(u"label_5")
        sizePolicy1 = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy1.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy1.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy1.setHeightForWidth(self.label_5.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_5.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy1)
        self.label_5.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_5)

        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(10)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.pushButton_1 = QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton_1.setObjectName(u"pushButton_1")
        sizePolicy2 = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy2.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy2.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_1.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_1.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
        self.pushButton_1.setBaseSize(QSize(0, 32))

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_1)

        self.label = QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.label.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setWordWrap(False)

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)


        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)

        self.verticalLayout_2 = QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(u"pushButton_2")
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)

        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)

        self.label_2 = QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName(u"label_2")
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.label_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2)


        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)


        self.verticalLayout_5.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(10)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_3")
        self.pushButton_3 = QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName(u"pushButton_3")
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)

        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)

        self.label_3 = QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_3.setObjectName(u"label_3")
        self.label_3.setEnabled(True)
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.label_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
        self.label_3.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_3)


        self.horizontalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_3)

        self.verticalLayout_4 = QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_4")
        self.pushButton_4 = QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName(u"pushButton_4")
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)

        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)

        self.label_4 = QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_4.setObjectName(u"label_4")
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.label_4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
        self.label_4.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_4)


        self.horizontalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_4)


        self.verticalLayout_5.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)

        main_window_class.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(main_window_class)
        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.label.update)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(main_window_class)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, main_window_class):
        main_window_class.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("main_window_class", u"main_window_class", None))
        self.label_5.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("main_window_class", u"TextLabel", None))
        self.pushButton_1.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("main_window_class", u"PushButton1", None))
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("main_window_class", u"TextLabel", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("main_window_class", u"PushButton2", None))
        self.label_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("main_window_class", u"TextLabel", None))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("main_window_class", u"PushButton3", None))
        self.label_3.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("main_window_class", u"TextLabel", None))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("main_window_class", u"PushButton4", None))
        self.label_4.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("main_window_class", u"TextLabel", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

3. xml формы.

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ui version="4.0">
     <class>main_window_class</class>
     <widget class="QMainWindow" name="main_window_class">
      <property name="enabled">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <width>663</width>
        <height>581</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="windowTitle">
       <string>main_window_class</string>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
       <widget class="QWidget" name="">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>20</x>
          <y>20</y>
          <width>611</width>
          <height>531</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
         <property name="spacing">
          <number>10</number>
         </property>
         <property name="leftMargin">
          <number>10</number>
         </property>
         <property name="topMargin">
          <number>10</number>
         </property>
         <property name="rightMargin">
          <number>10</number>
         </property>
         <property name="bottomMargin">
          <number>10</number>
         </property>
         <item>
          <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit"/>
         </item>
         <item>
          <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
           <property name="spacing">
            <number>10</number>
           </property>
           <property name="leftMargin">
            <number>10</number>
           </property>
           <property name="topMargin">
            <number>10</number>
           </property>
           <property name="rightMargin">
            <number>10</number>
           </property>
           <property name="bottomMargin">
            <number>10</number>
           </property>
           <item>
            <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2" stretch="0,0">
             <item>
              <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_1">
               <property name="sizePolicy">
                <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Fixed">
                 <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                 <verstretch>0</verstretch>
                </sizepolicy>
               </property>
               <property name="baseSize">
                <size>
                 <width>0</width>
                 <height>32</height>
                </size>
               </property>
               <property name="text">
                <string>PushButton1</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item>
              <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
               <property name="sizePolicy">
                <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Fixed">
                 <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                 <verstretch>0</verstretch>
                </sizepolicy>
               </property>
               <property name="text">
                <string>TextLabel 1</string>
               </property>
               <property name="alignment">
                <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
               </property>
               <property name="wordWrap">
                <bool>false</bool>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </item>
           <item>
            <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_6">
             <item>
              <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
               <property name="sizePolicy">
                <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Fixed">
                 <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                 <verstretch>0</verstretch>
                </sizepolicy>
               </property>
               <property name="text">
                <string>PushButton2</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item>
              <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
               <property name="sizePolicy">
                <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Fixed">
                 <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                 <verstretch>0</verstretch>
                </sizepolicy>
               </property>
               <property name="text">
                <string>TextLabel 2</string>
               </property>
               <property name="alignment">
                <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </item>
         <item>
          <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
           <property name="spacing">
            <number>10</number>
           </property>
           <property name="leftMargin">
            <number>10</number>
           </property>
           <property name="topMargin">
            <number>10</number>
           </property>
           <property name="rightMargin">
            <number>10</number>
           </property>
           <property name="bottomMargin">
            <number>10</number>
           </property>
           <item>
            <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3" stretch="0,0">
             <item>
              <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
               <property name="sizePolicy">
                <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Fixed">
                 <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                 <verstretch>0</verstretch>
                </sizepolicy>
               </property>
               <property name="text">
                <string>PushButton3</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item>
              <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
               <property name="enabled">
                <bool>true</bool>
               </property>
               <property name="sizePolicy">
                <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Fixed">
                 <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                 <verstretch>0</verstretch>
                </sizepolicy>
               </property>
               <property name="text">
                <string>TextLabel 3</string>
               </property>
               <property name="alignment">
                <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </item>
           <item>
            <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_4">
             <item>
              <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_4">
               <property name="sizePolicy">
                <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Fixed">
                 <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                 <verstretch>0</verstretch>
                </sizepolicy>
               </property>
               <property name="text">
                <string>PushButton4</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item>
              <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
               <property name="sizePolicy">
                <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred"
   ```

   vsizetype="Fixed">
   0
   0



   TextLabel 4


   Qt::AlignCenter

Исходники:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15wS4NieJ-KaYzrokZdodEmr1yPGWDVBY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: ВадимСоловьев, подправил форматирование ;)

Comment: А вы добавили сами layout на основной layout приложения? Кст, если можете, то добавьте файл `ui`, тогда можно будет вам помочь, подправив его. А так в дизайнере UI, тыкаете в пустое место окна и тыкаете на кнопку с тремя полосками `|||` или горизонтальными, так обозначаются вертикальные (QVBoxLayout) и горизонтальные (QHBoxLayout) компоновщики, тогда все виджеты/компоновщики встанут

Comment: @gil9red да - я так делал.
Ща скину ui.

Comment: @gil9red
Проблему решил, как Вы и сказали. Я делал просто не правильно: выбирал, что мне надо скомпоновать, а потом нажимал на 3 полоски. Почему так не получалость - я не понимаю. Ну да ладно - просто запомню. Огромнейшее спасибо!
Хотя все равно при запуске не так отображается, как в редакторе. Буду разбираться.  Пишите ответ - выберу лучшим.

Comment: Пожалуйста :) Добавил ответ. Кст, заметил по PushButton и TextLabel куча места, если что, вы можете прижать эти виджеты с помощью пружинок - Spacers (на скриншоте они есть слева в соответствующей группе, вам подойдет Vertical Spacer :)

Comment: @gil9red как обещал. за пружинки знаю, но все равно спасибо!  Я только перешел учить гуи после прочтения 3-х книг и двух курсов. Балуюсь с компонентами, а когда ознакомлюсь в общимх чертах поучу сигналы. Тогда может смогу уже попрактиковаться на какой-нибудь простой базе данных типа sqlite. Потом попробую kivy. просто мне надо будет в будущем програмки писать небольшие, но чтобы работали под всеми ОС кроме огрызка. Хочу разобраться с голосовым управлением. Гляди и умный дом напишу простой через годик. Есть zig-bee модули. Было бы круто.
,Спасибо за все!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Кликните по свободной области
2. Кликните на кнопку компоновки

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Теперь виджеты и компоновщики адаптируются по размеру:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]